Flow map with ggplot2
As discussed in this article: https://geographical.co.uk/geopolitics/how-maps-tell-the-story-of-war-in-ukraine , the following map is offering an interesting alternative to "arrow-based" flow maps.

The map is from this article -
https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-northern-ireland-60736603
I tried to reproduce with R & ggplot2
## Getting world map for mapping
europe <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(scale = "small", returnclass = "sf") |> 
  dplyr::filter(continent == "Europe")   
## check coord system
sf::st_crs(europe)

# Create some data
df <- data.frame(
  from = c("UKR","UKR"),
  to = c("POL","HUN"),
  ind = c(1525000,225000) ) |>
  ## add coordinates origin
  dplyr::left_join(
    europe  |> 
      sf::st_drop_geometry() |>
      dplyr::select(iso_a3, label_x, label_y) |>
      dplyr::rename("x"="label_x", "y"="label_y"),
    by=c("from"="iso_a3") ) |>
  ## add coordinates destination
  dplyr::left_join(
    europe  |> 
      sf::st_drop_geometry() |>
      dplyr::select(iso_a3, label_x, label_y) |>
      dplyr::rename("xend"="label_x", "yend"="label_y"),
    by=c("to"="iso_a3") ) |>
  # make spatial on destination...
  sf::st_as_sf( coords = c("xend","yend"), crs = 4326, remove=FALSE)

library(ggplot2)
# Plot
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = europe, fill = "antiquewhite", colour = "#7f7f7f", size = 0.2) + 
  ## arrows
  geom_curve( data = df,
              aes(xend= xend, yend= yend, 
                  x = x, y = y,
                  linewidth = ind), 
              alpha= .5 , curvature = -0.5 ,
              color = "blue",  
              show.legend = FALSE)+
  geom_sf(data = df,
          aes(size = ind),
          shape = 21,
          fill = "blue",
          color = "white",
           show.legend = FALSE) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(5, 45), ylim = c(35, 60), expand = FALSE) + ## Clipping  
  scale_size_area(max_size = 12,
                  labels = scales::label_number(
                    scale_cut = scales::cut_short_scale() ),
                  breaks = c(1e2, 1e4, 1e6)) + 
  theme_void() 

getting...

though it does not get this nice effect with the arrow starting with a point and matching the final circle size...

Tried a second attempt using bezier curve as ggforce::geom_bezier accept
linewidth = after_stat(index) as an aesthetic..
## Need a few function to create the mid point
## See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49327247/add-labels-to-the-center-of-a-geom-curve-line-ggplot
# Find origin of rotation
# Rotate around that origin
calcControlPoints <- function(x1, y1, x2, y2, curvature, angle, ncp,
                              debug=FALSE) {
  # Negative curvature means curve to the left
  # Positive curvature means curve to the right
  # Special case curvature = 0 (straight line) has been handled
  xm <- (x1 + x2)/2
  ym <- (y1 + y2)/2
  dx <- x2 - x1
  dy <- y2 - y1
  slope <- dy/dx
  
  # Calculate "corner" of region to produce control points in
  # (depends on 'angle', which MUST lie between 0 and 180)
  # Find by rotating start point by angle around mid point
  if (is.null(angle)) {
    # Calculate angle automatically
    angle <- ifelse(slope < 0,
                    2*atan(abs(slope)),
                    2*atan(1/slope))
  } else {
    angle <- angle/180*pi
  }
  sina <- sin(angle)
  cosa <- cos(angle)
  # FIXME:  special case of vertical or horizontal line ?
  cornerx <- xm + (x1 - xm)*cosa - (y1 - ym)*sina
  cornery <- ym + (y1 - ym)*cosa + (x1 - xm)*sina
  
  # Debugging
  if (debug) {
    grid.points(cornerx, cornery, default.units="inches",
                pch=16, size=unit(3, "mm"),
                gp=gpar(col="grey"))
  }
  
  # Calculate angle to rotate region by to align it with x/y axes
  beta <- -atan((cornery - y1)/(cornerx - x1))
  sinb <- sin(beta)
  cosb <- cos(beta)
  # Rotate end point about start point to align region with x/y axes
  newx2 <- x1 + dx*cosb - dy*sinb
  newy2 <- y1 + dy*cosb + dx*sinb
  
  # Calculate x-scale factor to make region "square"
  # FIXME:  special case of vertical or horizontal line ?
  scalex <- (newy2 - y1)/(newx2 - x1)
  # Scale end points to make region "square"
  newx1 <- x1*scalex
  newx2 <- newx2*scalex
  
  # Calculate the origin in the "square" region
  # (for rotating start point to produce control points)
  # (depends on 'curvature')
  # 'origin' calculated from 'curvature'
  ratio <- 2*(sin(atan(curvature))^2)
  origin <- curvature - curvature/ratio
  # 'hand' also calculated from 'curvature'
  if (curvature > 0)
    hand <- "right"
  else
    hand <- "left"
  oxy <- calcOrigin(newx1, y1, newx2, newy2, origin, hand)
  ox <- oxy$x
  oy <- oxy$y
  
  # Calculate control points
  # Direction of rotation depends on 'hand'
  dir <- switch(hand,
                left=-1,
                right=1)
  # Angle of rotation depends on location of origin
  maxtheta <- pi + sign(origin*dir)*2*atan(abs(origin))
  theta <- seq(0, dir*maxtheta,
               dir*maxtheta/(ncp + 1))[c(-1, -(ncp + 2))]
  costheta <- cos(theta)
  sintheta <- sin(theta)
  # May have BOTH multiple end points AND multiple
  # control points to generate (per set of end points)
  # Generate consecutive sets of control points by performing
  # matrix multiplication
  cpx <- ox + ((newx1 - ox) %*% t(costheta)) -
    ((y1 - oy) %*% t(sintheta))
  cpy <- oy + ((y1 - oy) %*% t(costheta)) +
    ((newx1 - ox) %*% t(sintheta))
  
  # Reverse transformations (scaling and rotation) to
  # produce control points in the original space
  cpx <- cpx/scalex
  sinnb <- sin(-beta)
  cosnb <- cos(-beta)
  finalcpx <- x1 + (cpx - x1)*cosnb - (cpy - y1)*sinnb
  finalcpy <- y1 + (cpy - y1)*cosnb + (cpx - x1)*sinnb
  
  # Debugging
  if (debug) {
    ox <- ox/scalex
    fox <- x1 + (ox - x1)*cosnb - (oy - y1)*sinnb
    foy <- y1 + (oy - y1)*cosnb + (ox - x1)*sinnb
    grid.points(fox, foy, default.units="inches",
                pch=16, size=unit(1, "mm"),
                gp=gpar(col="grey"))
    grid.circle(fox, foy, sqrt((ox - x1)^2 + (oy - y1)^2),
                default.units="inches",
                gp=gpar(col="grey"))
  }
  
  list(x=as.numeric(t(finalcpx)), y=as.numeric(t(finalcpy)))
}

calcOrigin <- function(x1, y1, x2, y2, origin, hand) {
  # Positive origin means origin to the "right"
  # Negative origin means origin to the "left"
  xm <- (x1 + x2)/2
  ym <- (y1 + y2)/2
  dx <- x2 - x1
  dy <- y2 - y1
  slope <- dy/dx
  oslope <- -1/slope
  # The origin is a point somewhere along the line between
  # the end points, rotated by 90 (or -90) degrees
  # Two special cases:
  # If slope is non-finite then the end points lie on a vertical line, so
  # the origin lies along a horizontal line (oslope = 0)
  # If oslope is non-finite then the end points lie on a horizontal line,
  # so the origin lies along a vertical line (oslope = Inf)
  tmpox <- ifelse(!is.finite(slope),
                  xm,
                  ifelse(!is.finite(oslope),
                         xm + origin*(x2 - x1)/2,
                         xm + origin*(x2 - x1)/2))
  tmpoy <- ifelse(!is.finite(slope),
                  ym + origin*(y2 - y1)/2,
                  ifelse(!is.finite(oslope),
                         ym,
                         ym + origin*(y2 - y1)/2))
  # ALWAYS rotate by -90 about midpoint between end points
  # Actually no need for "hand" because "origin" also
  # encodes direction
  # sintheta <- switch(hand, left=-1, right=1)
  sintheta <- -1
  ox <- xm - (tmpoy - ym)*sintheta
  oy <- ym + (tmpox - xm)*sintheta
  
  list(x=ox, y=oy)
}

## Getting world map for mapping
europe <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(scale = "small", returnclass = "sf") |> 
  dplyr::filter(continent == "Europe")   
## check coord system
sf::st_crs(europe)

# Create some data
df <- data.frame(
  from = c("UKR","UKR"),
  to = c("POL","HUN"),
  colour = c("#0072BC","#0072BC"),
  ind = c(1525000,225000) ) |>
  ## add coordinates origin
  dplyr::left_join(
    europe  |> 
      sf::st_drop_geometry() |>
      dplyr::select(iso_a3, label_x, label_y) |>
      dplyr::rename("x"="label_x", "y"="label_y"),
    by=c("from"="iso_a3") ) |>
  ## add coordinates destination
  dplyr::left_join(
    europe  |> 
      sf::st_drop_geometry() |>
      dplyr::select(iso_a3, label_x, label_y) |>
      dplyr::rename("xend"="label_x", "yend"="label_y"),
    by=c("to"="iso_a3") ) |>
  ## add one middle bezier point
  dplyr::mutate(midx = calcControlPoints(x, y, xend, yend, 
                                         angle = 130, 
                                         curvature = 0.5, 
                                         ncp = 1)$x) |> 
  dplyr::mutate(midy = calcControlPoints(x, y, xend, yend, 
                                         angle = 130, 
                                         curvature = 0.5, 
                                         ncp = 1)$y) |>
  # name curve
  dplyr::mutate(curve = paste0(from,"_",to),
                type = "cubic") |>
  # make spatial on destination...
  sf::st_as_sf( coords = c("xend","yend"), crs = 4326, remove=FALSE)

## Creating the frame to build the curved bezier lines
df_curve <- df |>
  sf::st_drop_geometry() |>
  dplyr::select(curve, type, colour, x,midx,xend) |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer( cols = c("x","midx","xend"),
                       values_to = "x") |>
  cbind ( df |>
            sf::st_drop_geometry() |>
            dplyr::select(y,midy,yend) |>
            tidyr::pivot_longer( cols = c("y","midy","yend"),
                                 values_to = "y")) |>
  dplyr::select(curve, type, colour, x,y)  
  


library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = europe, fill = "antiquewhite",
          colour = "#7f7f7f", size = 0.2) + 
  # Now the proportional symbol
  geom_sf(data = df, 
         aes(size = ind),
          shape = 21,
          fill = "blue",
          color = "white", 
         show.legend = FALSE) +
  ## arrows
  ggforce::geom_bezier( data = df_curve ,
                        aes(x = x, y = y,
                            group = curve,
                            linewidth = after_stat(index),
                            linetype = type,
                            color = colour,
                            alpha = 0.2  ),
                        show.legend = FALSE )  +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(5, 45), ylim = c(35, 60), expand = FALSE) + ## Clipping  
  scale_size_area(max_size = 12,
                  labels = scales::label_number(scale_cut = scales::cut_short_scale()),
                  breaks = c(1e2, 1e4, 1e6)) +  
  theme_void() 

Here's the result -

Though the final end of the bezier curve is not at the same scale than the point... It seems there's no scale_size_linewidth
Also I guess  geom_bezier linewidth should be linked to ind  and the geom_bezier colors are not recognized...
any hint to do that programmatically with R/ggplot2?

Bubble plot on a map is pretty straightforward. Add the trails in post-hoc with a graphic design program.

well - the idea is to find a smart way to do it programmatically with ggplot2..

Start with some sample data and show your best attempt. But it's not a standard ggplot feature, or one I've seen in any add-on packages.

@GregorThomas - sorry - you are right - now done!

Where do europe$label_x and europe$label_y come from?

europe$label_x and europe$label_y are defined coordinates for country labels available within the package rnaturalearth::ne_countries

With your edits, the question looks very good now. I've voted to reopen, however it can be slow to get attention for reopen votes. You're probably better off asking a new question.

You were almost there. The issue with the color is that you mapped on the color aesthetic instead of setting the color as a parameter. Concerning the issue with the linewidth and the size. As the size of the points is set such the area reflects the value you have to set linewidth according to the diameter, i.e. map sqrt(ind / pi) on linewidth. To account for that and still have a linewidth varying with the index I use stage() instead of after_stat():
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = europe, fill = "antiquewhite", colour = "#7f7f7f", size = 0.2) +
  ggforce::geom_bezier(
    data = df_curve,
    aes(
      x = x, y = y,
      group = curve,
      linewidth = stage(ind, after_stat = sqrt(linewidth / pi) * index),
      linetype = type,
      alpha = after_stat(index),
    ),
    color = "#0072BC",
    show.legend = FALSE,
    n = 300
  ) +
  geom_sf(
    data = df,
    aes(size = ind),
    shape = 21,
    fill = "#0072BC",
    color = "white",
    show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  scale_alpha_continuous(
    range = c(.1, .5)
  ) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(15, 35), ylim = c(45, 55), expand = FALSE) +
  scale_linewidth_continuous(
    range = c(0, 36)
  ) +
  scale_size_area(
    max_size = 36,
    labels = scales::label_number(
      scale_cut = scales::cut_short_scale()
    ),
    breaks = c(1e2, 1e4, 1e6)
  ) +
  theme_void()


